# BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am writing an Android application for version 4.0.3 (ICS) of the Android OS. The issue is that I am not getting the output from my Log.d() in the onReceive() method of the BroadcastReceiver which means my application is not properly handling the broadcast.

I have read countless questions about how to run code upon a ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON being clicked. I have even copy + pasted code when mine did not work, just to see if it would work.

The ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON I want to handle is the **single** button on earphones that allow a user to pickup / end calls, play / pause music. **Instead of my application handling this button, when I click it, the stock music player on my Nexus S Android starts playing a song**.

I have not placed my code in another class, maybe this is why it's not working?

Here's the code found on the onCreate() method (this specific code I copied off a website after the code I wrote didn't work):

```
IntentFilter mediaButtonFilter = new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    mediaButtonFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
    BroadcastReceiver brMediaButton = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("Event", "Media button!");
            this.abortBroadcast();

            KeyEvent key = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if(key.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                int keycode = key.getKeyCode();
                if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT) {
                    Log.d("TestApp", "Next Pressed");
                } else if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS) {
                    Log.d("TestApp", "Previous pressed");
                } else if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {
                    Log.d("TestApp", "Head Set Hook pressed");
                }
            }

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(brMediaButton, mediaButtonFilter);
```

All I really need to test for is the KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK but it doesn't hurt to have the other code there for testing, I'll fix it up once I can get everything working correctly.

In my manifest:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
```

I originally thought this may be a permissions issue since I didn't specify any permissions for this however I didn't receive any error message.

Like I said earlier, I have tried many variations of this. One example was the use of the code at this link [broadcastreceiver onReceive problem ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603170/broadcastreceiver-onreceive-problem-action-media-button-android) with CommonsWare's corrections. Again, however, I modified it so it wasn't in a seperate class.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369554/how-to-handle-long-press-media-button-in-order-to-launch-activity) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603170/broadcastreceiver-onreceive-problem-action-media-button-android)

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I have almost the same code as you and it's working fine on Android 2.2 / 2.3. But like you I can't make it work with ICS...

Comment: Same here.  It works before Android 4.0.  The API changed or something.

Comment: I have started a bounty on the same issue I think...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257982/mediabuttonintentreceiver-not-working-in-android-4-0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tested this on a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 4.4.2. So what is important and what **is not mentioned in other posts**:

- Register the receiver in the *AndroidManifest.xml* inside the *application* tag but outside from every *activity* tag.
- Your receiver *Broadcastreceiver* need to be public and static
- One activity need to register an *MediaButtonEventReceiver* to listen for the button presses

Okay and here some **example code**:

```
mAudioManager =  (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(this,YourBroadcastReceiver.class);
...
mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent);
...
// somewhere else
mAudioManager.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent);
```

Here the **receiver**:

```
public static class YourBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    // Constructor is mandatory
    public MediaBroadcastReceiver ()
    {
        super ();
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        Log.i (TAG_MEDIA, intentAction.toString() + " happended");
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            Log.i (TAG_MEDIA, "no media button information");
            return;
        }
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null) {
            Log.i (TAG_MEDIA, "no keypress");
            return;
        }
        // other stuff you want to do
    }
}
```

And here the **manifest** snippet. If needed add priority for the intent-filter, but was not needed for me:

```
<application>
    <receiver android:name="OuterClass$YourBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
         </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity> ... </activity>
</application>
```

For the references:

- http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html
- [MediaButtonIntentReceiver not working in Android 4.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257982/mediabuttonintentreceiver-not-working-in-android-4-0)
- [BroadcastReceiver: can't instantiate class; no empty constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305261/broadcastreceiver-cant-instantiate-class-no-empty-constructor/10305338#10305338)

Comment: I am trying to implement same in Samsung device when my activity going into background onReceive() always call but in nexus onReceive() never called in background. can you just explain why?

Answer (score 4):

```
mediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MediaButtonReceiver.class.getName());

mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaButtonReceiver);
```

This code will bind your headphone button to your app and your app only until you call:

```
mAudioManager.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaButtonReceiver);
```

Comment: Or until other app calls `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()`, I would way ;)

Comment: Where I can register the broadcast . I have registered the Receiver in Manifest file only

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid to use the Broacastreceiver for Android >5.0 (API level 21 LOLLIPOP) using the MediaSession described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413753/1386969