# BroadcastReceiver: can't instantiate class; no empty constructor

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have inner class as broadcast receiver:

```
public class ManualBacklightReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String ACTION_MANUAL_BACKLIGHT = "com.android.systemui.statusbar.powerwidget.MANUAL_BACKLIGHT";

    public ManualBacklightReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("ManualBacklightReceiver", intent.getAction());
    }

};
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".statusbar.powerwidget.PowerWidgetGrid$ManualBacklightReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.systemui.statusbar.powerwidget.MANUAL_BACKLIGHT"/>
        </intent-filter>            
    </receiver>
```

And when I send the intent with this code:
Intent intent = new Intent();

```
intent.setAction("com.android.systemui.statusbar.powerwidget.MANUAL_BACKLIGHT");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I get these exceptions:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.android.systemui.statusbar.powerwidget.PowerWidgetGrid$ManualBacklightReceiver:
java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.android.systemui.statusbar.powerwidget.PowerWidgetGrid$ManualBacklightReceiver; no empty constructor
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.android.systemui.statusbar.powerwidget.PowerWidgetGrid$ManualBacklightReceiver; no empty constructor
```

But I have an empty constructor! Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried calling the super(); inside of your constructor?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You need to declare your inner class as static. Otherwise, an inner class is associated with an *instance* of your outer class.

Check out the [Java Nested Classes tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for details. Here is a snippet:

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of
>   OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its
>   enclosing instance. The next figure illustrates this idea.

and:

> A nested class is a member of its enclosing class. Non-static nested
>   classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing
>   class, even if they are declared private. Static nested classes do not
>   have access to other members of the enclosing class. As a member of
>   the OuterClass, a nested class can be declared private, public,
>   protected, or package private. (Recall that outer classes can only be
>   declared public or package private.)

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. But I can not access the fields of OuterClass instance from nested class? What should I do, if the outer class is the view, and I need to modify it when the intent is received?

Comment: @RankoR: "But I can not access the fields of OuterClass instance from nested class?" -- correct. "What should I do, if the outer class is the view, and I need to modify it when the intent is received?" -- register your `BroadcastReceiver` via `registerReceiver()` from your `Activity`, rather than via the manifest.

Comment: I tried to do it this way, but it doesn't work, method onReceive is not called. Receiver was created correctly. I'm doing it in the SystemUI package from Android source.