# Cannot get BroadcastReceiver working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to use the HEADSETHOOK button (keycode 79) on my Samsung earphones but cannot get it to work.  I am, essentially, following the answer given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177417/broadcastreceiver-for-action-media-button-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1) SO question.  My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android v8.

The relevant part of my manifest is:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity$HeadsetBtnReceiver" android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10000000" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My Activity (which includes the BroadcastReceiver) is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static AudioManager mAudioManager;
static ComponentName mReceiverComponent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(this, HeadsetBtnReceiver.class);
    mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent);

}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.e("Udp", "Backpress MainActivity");
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e("UDP svc", "Destroying MainActivity");
    mAudioManager.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent);
    finish();
    super.onDestroy();
}

public static class HeadsetBtnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Constructor is mandatory

    public HeadsetBtnReceiver()
    {
        super ();
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        Log.e("Udp svc", intentAction.toString() + " happened");
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            Log.e("Udp svc", "no media button information");
            return;
        }
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null) {
            Log.e("Udp svc", "no keypress");
            return;
        }

        KeyEvent key = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        Log.e("UDP svc", "KeyEvent : ");

        if(key.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            int keycode = key.getKeyCode();
            if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT) {
                Log.e("Udp svc", "Next Pressed");
            } else if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS) {
                Log.e("Udp svc", "Previous pressed");
            } else if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {
                Log.e("Udp svc", "Head Set Hook pressed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I run the app I get no Logcat messages, all that happens is that I get the default actions for both the volume buttons and the other, single, button.

I believe that the BroadcastReceiver has been deprecated in favour of MediaSession but as far as I can make out that only recognises the volume buttons.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try registering for it dynamically as a test, using `registerReceiver()`. If that works, then your problem is that [most implicit broadcasts are banned on Android 8.0+](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html). If `registerReceiver()` also fails, then either you have the wrong `Intent` action or the device simply is not broadcasting it when you think it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However I still can't get it working and am clearly doing something wrong.  See my comment below @Pawel's answer for more detail

Answer (score 0):

Move your receiver from manifest into a regular receiver object You will register at runtime. Broadcasts receivers declared in manifest no longer work from android O (few exceptions apply).

> As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits,
>   apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register
>   broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.

More details: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I've now done this (as far as I'm aware) but am still not getting any responses when I press the headset button,  I have removed the <receiver> entry from the manifest and created a broadcastreceiver instance called headsetBtnReceiver (based on the public static class HeadsetBtnReceiver declared within the MainActivity) and registered this with the intentfilter ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON all of which is immediately before the AudioManager statements.  But still it isn't working. What am I doing wrong or missing?